# With the plethora of programming languages out there, why are there not separate communities for each?

Tags: feature-request

With the plethora of programming languages out there, why are there not separate communities for each instead of them all being lumped into StackOverflow?

Nobody is an expert in all of the programming languages in StackOverflow and nobody uses all of the languages. So, why not have separate communities for each?

Comment: Because many people are experts in *more than one language*.

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [It's so inconvinient! Why not separating?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75766)

Comment: I have a lot of tags in my ignore list. For me no php, java and android... I forgot to mention python...

Comment: *Nobody is an expert in all of the programming languages in StackOverflow.* Who knows? Maybe someone is. Do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: Also, there are many design problems that are language-agnostic, even if the OP only wants a solution for one language.

Comment: Who's going to decide the dividing lines? Am I going to post a question regarding some issue with "my website coding" on `javascript.stackoverflow.com` or `angular.stackoverflow.com` or both or neither? How is that better than tagging a question with both [tag:javascript] and [tag:angular]?

Comment: Also: I find the cross-pollination to be one of the most valuable things on SO.

Comment: *Nobody is an expert in all of the programming languages in StackOverflow.* You obvisouly haven't met Jon Skeet

Comment: Related: [Introduce sub-communities or "portals" to prevent fragmentation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94591)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because they all overlap and usually a programmer uses more than one in conjunction with each other to create advanced software

Answer (score 9):

I'll take the Oracle RDBMS as an example; it's my day job:

So, we start with the RDBMS Oracle and the assumption this should be on it's own, which you can run SQL, DML and DCL against (the same but slightly different to the versions of SQL used by SQL Server, MySQL, Sybase, Firebird, Google Big Table, DB2, YQL, HQL etc.) Oracle also uses PL/SQL, which is based on Ada (both of which are based on Pascal), is very similar to PL/pgSQL, and can be compiled by DB2 and TimesTen.

Now, just to connect to the database you need some understanding of TNS and TCP/IP with SSL. But you probably need some knowledge of JDBC or ODBC, depending on the application you're using. If you go down the OCI or OCCI route you're probably using C or C++ (which you can compile in the database) but you might also end up using Pro*C or Pro*COBOL (yes COBOL) or Pro*FORTRAN.

Now, you discover that you can't do everything in the database that you want to; luckily it runs the JVM (Oracle being what it is and all), which means you can compile Java directly (or Jython - based on Python, which has a core of C... -  you can compile this remember)

I haven't really followed all the stuff based on the languages/protocols I've mentioned yet; this is just what you *might* need to know if you use Oracle.

That's why.